# Como setar Title em uma `img`?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Existe alguma forma de setar o título `(Text)` do componente `img` no `code behind`?

```
<tr>
   <td colspan="7">
      <img id="ProximoMes" src="../Images/Icons/dright.gif" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: você quis dizer o atributo `alt` do <img> ?

Comment: Explique o que você chama de *title*. O que quer exatamente?

Comment: @bigown , seria o texto que a imagem apresenta quando o link (src) não é encontrado, peguei uma aplicação para fazer manutenção e me deparei com isso   `<img id="ProximoMes" title="Próximo Mês"  runat="server" src="../Images/Icons/dright.gif" />`, estou levando tudo que é **TEXT** para o **code behind** para fazer tradução para outros idiomas, mas pelo que pesquisei o componente IMG do .NET não tem o _title_ .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso pode ser colocado no *code behind* assim:

```
this.ProximoMes.Attributes.Add("title", "Alguma coisa aqui");
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/ASP.NET/ChangeAttribute.cs).

Comment: Isso mesmo vlw.

Comment: faltou dizer que ele precisa colocar o runat="server"

Comment: Esta nos comentários .